# Any rule about superheroes and hyphens in their names?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, names

You really know this fact that Spider-man is hyphenated.

But why? Any grammatical rule?

Is he unique hero written with a hyphen, unlike Batman, Superman etc.?

Comment: Batman was originally the Bat-Man.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about the reasons authors have/had for making choices in using allowable English forms, rather than English.

Comment: I do not agree. It could have been for some English grammar reason, just because it was not does not mean it is off topic

Comment: I do not see why this is getting 4 close votes. The question is about grammatical reasons for hyphenating a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems he is unique and it was to offset his name from Superman:

[Why Stan Lee put a hyphen in Spider-man](http://www.blastr.com/2013-7-16/little-known-sci-fi-fact-why-stan-lee-put-hyphen-spider-man)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no real reason actually! May be just to distinguish that name from other super hero names like Superman or Batman.

Comment: beacuse at first glance maybe Spiderman can be misead as Superman as Superman was feed to our mind earlier than Spiderman. I guess this may be the reason.

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: No, but when I answered the page reloaded and showed your answer. No offence :)